# How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes

Tags: powershell, parameters, quotes, exe, spaces

How do you run the following command in PowerShell?

> C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224638/powershell-call-msbuild-with-nested-quotation-marks/8468690#8468690

Comment: If you mean litteraly "in PowerShell" (which I interpret to mean "inside an existing PowerShell prompt), then the following example can be easilyt adpated to suite your needs. Notice there is no need to separate the command from its parameters:

`# Show any available updates to globally installed npm packages using the npm-check-updates tool

[string] $cmd = 'ncu -g'
Write-Verbose -Message $cmd
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create($cmd))
`

Comment: I have no idea how to use "mini-markdown" to edit the above comment to make each line of code appear on a separate line and the 5 minute time limit on editing the original comment has expired.  If anybody knows now to use "mini-Markdown" to fix the problem, I'll repost in a more readable form.

The first line should be just the following:

# Show any available updates to globally installed npm packages using the npm-check-updates tool

Comment: I've never known comments to be able allow different lines. The markdown features are limited to `backticks` and ()[] for links in comments, I think.

Comment: How do I run a command from a shell? -> 21 answers, many of which take a page or more. If someone asked me *one* reason why I consider Powershell a complete failure, this would be the answer.

Comment: Running an external command with params in Powershell should be much easier than it actually is.  So many gotchas and nuances

Answer (score 473):

When PowerShell sees a command starting with a string it just evaluates the string, that is, it typically echos it to the screen, for example:

```
PS> "Hello World"
Hello World
```

If you want PowerShell to interpret the string as a command name then use the call operator (&) like so:

```
PS> & 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe'
```

After that you probably only need to quote parameter/argument pairs that contain spaces and/or quotation chars. When you invoke an EXE file like this with complex command line arguments it is usually very helpful to have a tool that will show you how PowerShell sends the arguments to the EXE file. The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) has such a tool. It is called echoargs. You just replace the EXE file with echoargs - leaving all the arguments in place, and it will show you how the EXE file will receive the arguments, for example:

```
PS> echoargs -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass

Arg 0 is <-verb:sync>
Arg 1 is <-source:dbfullsql=Data>
Arg 2 is <Source=mysource;Integrated>
Arg 3 is <Security=false;User>
Arg 4 is <ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;>
Arg 5 is <-dest:dbfullsql=Data>
Arg 6 is <Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated>
Arg 7 is <Security=false;User>
Arg 8 is <ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb; computername=10.10.10.10 username=administrator password=adminpass>
```

Using echoargs you can experiment until you get it right, for example:

```
PS> echoargs -verb:sync "-source:dbfullsql=Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;"
Arg 0 is <-verb:sync>
Arg 1 is <-source:dbfullsql=Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;>
```

It turns out I was trying too hard before to maintain the double quotes around the connection string. Apparently that isn't necessary because even cmd.exe will strip those out.

BTW, hats off to the PowerShell team. They were quite helpful in showing me the specific incantation of single & double quotes to get the desired result - if you needed to keep the internal double quotes in place. :-)  They also realize this is an area of pain, but they are driven by the number of folks are affected by a particular issue. If this is an area of pain for you, then please vote up this [PowerShell bug submission](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=376207).

For more information on how PowerShell parses, check out my [Effective PowerShell blog series](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=cat%3dEffective%2520PowerShell) - specifically [item 10 - "Understanding PowerShell Parsing Modes"](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/)

UPDATE 4/4/2012: This situation gets much easier to handle in PowerShell V3. See this [blog post for details](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/).

Comment: if using as second example, i get this error: 
Error: Unrecognized argument '"-source:dbfullsql="""Data'. All arguments must begin with "-".

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  I see that, currently, 6 people have upvoted the answer so I am missing something obvious, but what is the actual answer?  Is there a special rule to know about parameters with spaces with PowerShell, or are you just suggesting to take it case-by-case, using EchoArgs to help?

Comment: Quoting the arguments is usually sufficient but not always.  In those cases where it doesn't work, using `echoargs` gives an indication of how PowerShell is interpreting the arguments before it passes them onto the EXE.

Comment: Do you know how I would do this in a .bat file? I'm trying `& 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'` directly in the console and it's working, but in a batch file I get an error saying '& was unexpected at this time.'

Comment: Nevermind. Found it: `START C:\"Program Files"\"Sublime Text 3"\sublime_text.exe`

Comment: @Keith Hill, This tool amassing. you saved my life. Thank you so much.

Comment: Chrome labels http://pscx.codeplex.com/ as containing harmful programs :\ Is https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx the right link?

Comment: As Codeplex is read only now, it would be good to update that link.

Comment: Crazy. Who dreamt up the call operator?! The amount of time I've wasted trying to get an exe to run was insane. Is it a CrippleShell-only feature?

Comment: And why can't you make the Powershell window wider by dragging it?!

Answer (score 95):

I had spaces in both command and parameters, and this is what worked for me:

```
$Command = "E:\X64\Xendesktop Setup\XenDesktopServerSetup.exe"
$Parms = "/COMPONENTS CONTROLLER,DESKTOPSTUDIO,DESKTOPDIRECTOR,LICENSESERVER,STOREFRONT /PASSIVE /NOREBOOT /CONFIGURE_FIREWALL /NOSQL"

$Parms = $Parms.Split(" ")
& "$Command" $Parms
```

It's basically the same as Akira's answer, but this works if you dynamically build your command parameters and put them in a variable.

Comment: imho this is the best! no base64, no strange --% syntax which toggles substitution, normal powershell substitution rules, no confusion, very readable.

Comment: This doesn't work.  If your parameter has a path name in it, the path name will be divided into multiple parameters.

Comment: Nice answer. However, will it work with quotes in the parameters?

Comment: Please try this, after everything else this actually worked. And also use the Powershell Extension `EchoArgs`

Comment: The `.Split(" ")` was the key part of this answer that made it work for me

Answer (score 83):

Just add the **&** operator before the .exe name. 
Here is a command to install SQL Server Express in silence mode:

```
$fileExe = "T:\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe"
$CONFIGURATIONFILE = "T:\ConfSetupSql2008Express.ini"

& $fileExe  /CONFIGURATIONFILE=$CONFIGURATIONFILE
```

Answer (score 72):

There are quite a few methods you can use to do it.

> There are other methods like using the Call Operator (**&**), **Invoke-Expression** cmdlet etc. But they are considered unsafe. Microsoft recommends using **Start-Process**.

**Method 1**

A simple example

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql" -ArgumentList "-u root","-proot","-h localhost"
```

In your case

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -ArgumentList "-verb:sync","-source:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`"","-dest:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`"","computername=10.10.10.10","username=administrator","password=adminpass"
```

In this method you separate each and every parameter in the ArgumentList using commas.

**Method 2**

Simple Example

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin\mysql" -ArgumentList "-u root -proot -h localhost"
```

In your case

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -ArgumentList "-verb:sync -source:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`" -dest:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass"
```

This method is easier as it allows to type your parameters in one go.

> Note that in powershell to represent the **quotation mark ( " ) in a string** you should insert the **grave accent ( ` )** (This is the key above the Tab key in the US keyboard).
>
> **-NoNewWindow**
> parameter is used to display the new process in the current console window. By default Windows PowerShell opens a new window.

References : [Powershell/Scripting/Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Simple always wins! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the final note on escaping the quotation mark!

Answer (score 50):

This worked for me:

```
& 'D:\Server\PSTools\PsExec.exe' @('\\1.1.1.1', '-accepteula', '-d', '-i', $id, '-h', '-u', 'domain\user', '-p', 'password', '-w', 'C:\path\to\the\app', 'java', '-jar', 'app.jar')
```

Just put paths or connection strings in one array item and split the other things in one array item each.

There are a lot of other options here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Microsoft should make this way simpler and compatible with command prompt syntax.

Comment: Array is definitely the best option - this worked great for me. Except I passed an array variable because my arguments were dynamic. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO best solution

Comment: This works great in Powershell 7, not in 5.1

Answer (score 24):

In case somebody is wondering how to just run an executable file:

..... >  .\file.exe

or

......>  full\path\to\file.exe

Comment: This should be the answer for that question, it's what we are looking for when we search with "Start EXE from PowerShell" keywords. Thank you !

Comment: How about running with arguments?

Comment: @SereneWizard Well, add them after .exe with a space inbetween. Example:  .\file.exe param1 param2 param3

Comment: This will fail as soon as there are spaces in the command's name. Then you have to wrap the command in quotes. Then it will be considered just a string by Powershell, and will just be output, instead of the command being started, which brings us back to the OP's problem.

Comment: this one should be considered the correct answer.

Answer (score 23):

See this page:
https://slai.github.io/posts/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Summary using vshadow as the external executable:

```
$exe = "H:\backup\scripts\vshadow.exe"
&$exe -p -script=H:\backup\scripts\vss.cmd E: M: P:
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -ArgumentList "-verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass"
```

The key thing to note here is that FilePath must be in position 0, according to the Help Guide. To invoke the Help guide for a commandlet, just type in `Get-Help <Commandlet-name> -Detailed` . In this case, it is `Get-Help Start-Process -Detailed`.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get my similar command working using the following approach:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb=sync "-source=dbFullSql=Server=THESERVER;Database=myDB;UID=sa;Pwd=saPwd" -dest=dbFullSql=c:\temp\test.sql
```

For your command (not that it helps much now), things would look something like this:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb=sync "-source=dbfullsql=Server=mysource;Trusted_Connection=false;UID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" "-dest=dbfullsql=Server=mydestsource;Trusted_Connection=false;UID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass
```

The key points are:

- Use quotes around the source argument, and remove the embedded quotes around the connection string
- Use the alternative key names in building the SQL connection string that don't have spaces in them.  For example, use "UID" instead of "User Id", "Server" instead of "Data Source", "Trusted_Connection" instead of "Integrated Security", and so forth.  I was only able to get it to work once I removed all spaces from the connection string.

I didn't try adding the "computername" part at the end of the command line, but hopefully this info will help others reading this now get closer to their desired result.

Comment: I tried all other answers, but this was the only answer that worked for me! Thanks for providing this alternative path.

Comment: This will fail as soon as there are spaces in the command's name. Then you have to wrap the command in quotes. Then it will be considered just a string by Powershell, and will just be output, instead of the command being started, which brings us back to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 9):

New escape string in PowerShell V3, quoted from *[New V3 Language Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx)*:

> Easier Reuse of Command Lines From Cmd.exe

The web is full of command lines written for Cmd.exe. These commands lines work often enough in PowerShell, but when they include certain characters, for example, a semicolon (;), a dollar sign ($), or curly braces, you have to make some changes, probably adding some quotes. This seemed to be the source of many minor headaches.

To help address this scenario, we added a new way to “escape” the parsing of command lines. If you use a magic parameter --%, we stop our normal parsing of your command line and switch to something much simpler. We don’t match quotes. We don’t stop at semicolon. We don’t expand PowerShell variables. We do expand environment variables if you use Cmd.exe syntax (e.g. %TEMP%). Other than that, the arguments up to the end of the line (or pipe, if you are piping) are passed as is. Here is an example:

```
PS> echoargs.exe --% %USERNAME%,this=$something{weird}
Arg 0 is <jason,this=$something{weird}>
```

Answer (score 7):

I use this simple, clean and effective method.

I place arguments in an array, 1 per line. This way it is very easy to read and edit.
Then I use a simple trick of passing all arguments inside double quotes to a function with 1 single parameter. That flattens them, including arrays, to a single string, which I then execute using PS's 'Invoke-Expression'. This directive is specifically designed to convert a string to runnable command.
Works well:

```
# function with one argument will flatten 
# all passed-in entries into 1 single string line
Function Execute($command) {
    # execute:
    Invoke-Expression $command;
    # if you have trouble try:
    # Invoke-Expression "& $command";
    # or if you need also output to a variable
    # Invoke-Expression $command | Tee-Object -Variable cmdOutput;
}

#  ... your main code here ...

# The name of your executable app
$app = 'my_app.exe';
# List of arguments:
# Notice the type of quotes - important !
# Those in single quotes are normal strings, like 'Peter'
$args = 'arg1',
        'arg2',
        $some_variable,
        'arg4',
        "arg5='with quotes'",
        'arg6',
        "arg7 \ with \ $other_variable",
        'etc...';
    
# pass all arguments inside double quotes
Execute "$app $args";
```

Comment: The part about putting each param into an array has help me immensely!

Answer (score 5):

You can run exe files in powershell different ways. For instance if you want to run unrar.exe and extract a .rar file you can simply write in powershell this:

```
$extract_path = "C:\Program Files\Containing folder";
$rar_to_extract = "C:\Path_to_arch\file.rar"; #(or.exe if its a big file)  
C:\Path_here\Unrar.exe x -o+ -c- $rar_to_extract $extract_path;
```

But sometimes, this doesn't work so you must use the & parameter as shown above:
For instance, with vboxmanage.exe (a tool to manage virtualbox virtual machines) you must call the paramterers outside of the string like this, without quotes:

```
> $vmname = "misae_unrtes_1234123"; #(name too long, we want to change this)
> & 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe' modifyvm $vmname --name UBUNTU;
```

If you want to call simply a winrar archived file as .exe files, you can also unzip it with the invoke-command cmdlet and a Silent parameter /S (Its going to extract itself in the same folder than where it has been compressed).

```
> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { C:\Your-path\archivefile.exe /S };
```

So there are several ways to run .exe files with arguments in powershell.

Sometimes, one must find a workaround to make it work properly, which can require some further effort and pain :) depending on the way the .exe has been compiled or made by its creators.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the suggestions but was still unable to run `msiexec.exe` with parameters that contained spaces. So my solution ended up using `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`:

```
# can have spaces here, no problems
$settings = @{
  CONNECTION_STRING = "... ..."
  ENTITY_CONTEXT = "... ..."
  URL = "..."
}

$settingsJoined = ($settings.Keys | % { "$_=""$($settings[$_])""" }) -join " "
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.WorkingDirectory = $ScriptDirectory
$pinfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = "/l* install.log /i installer.msi $settingsJoined"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$p.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Do not read from StandardOutput with ReadToEnd() **after** you wait for exit. It creates a deadlock. Put it before the method "WaitForExit()"
See: [Microsoft Docs - Diagnostic.Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-process-standardoutput)

Answer (score 3):

Cmd can handle running a quoted exe, but Powershell can't.  I'm just going to deal with running the exe itself, since I don't have it.  If you literally need to send doublequotes to an argument of an external command, that's another issue that's been covered elsewhere.

1) add the exe folder to your path, maybe in your $profile

```
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\'
msdeploy
```

2) backquote the spaces:

```
C:\Program` Files\IIS\Microsoft` Web` Deploy\msdeploy.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "& ""C:\Some Script\Path With Spaces.ps1"""
```

The key seems to be that the whole command is enclosed in outer quotes, the "&" ampersand is used to specify another child command file is being executed, then finally escaped (doubled-double-) quotes around the path/file name with spaces in you wanted to execute in the first place.

This is also completion of the only workaround to the MS connect issue that -File does not pass-back non-zero return codes and -Command is the only alternative. But until now it was thought a limitation of -Command was that it didn't support spaces. I've updated that feedback item too.

http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/750653/powershell-exe-doesn-t-return-correct-exit-codes-when-using-the-file-option

Comment: This is unrelated to the ops question, he specifically asked how to run the long command in his post in powershell. Not how to run a powershell script with spaces in the file path.

Comment: Read the title of the question, spaces are the issue not length. This is one valid answer to such problems so worthwhile sharing. Did you have the same problem and actually try it? If you want to improve it submit an edit which includes the actual command in the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer is to use a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded command switch:

```
powershell -EncodedCommand "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"
```

When decoded, you'll see it's the OP's original snippet with all arguments and double quotes preserved.

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand

Accepts a base-64-encoded string version of a command. Use this parameter
to submit commands to Windows PowerShell that require complex quotation
marks or curly braces.
```

The original command:

```
 C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass"
```

It turns into this when encoded as Base64:

```
QwA6AFwAUAByAG8AZwByAGEAbQAgAEYAaQBsAGUAcwBcAEkASQBTAFwATQBpAGMAcgBvAHMAbwBmAHQAIABXAGUAYgAgAEQAZQBwAGwAbwB5AFwAbQBzAGQAZQBwAGwAbwB5AC4AZQB4AGUAIAAtAHYAZQByAGIAOgBzAHkAbgBjACAALQBzAG8AdQByAGMAZQA6AGQAYgBmAHUAbABsAHMAcQBsAD0AIgBEAGEAdABhACAAUwBvAHUAcgBjAGUAPQBtAHkAcwBvAHUAcgBjAGUAOwBJAG4AdABlAGcAcgBhAHQAZQBkACAAUwBlAGMAdQByAGkAdAB5AD0AZgBhAGwAcwBlADsAVQBzAGUAcgAgAEkARAA9AHMAYQA7AFAAdwBkAD0AcwBhAHAAYQBzAHMAIQA7AEQAYQB0AGEAYgBhAHMAZQA9AG0AeQBkAGIAOwAiACAALQBkAGUAcwB0ADoAZABiAGYAdQBsAGwAcwBxAGwAPQAiAEQAYQB0AGEAIABTAG8AdQByAGMAZQA9AC4AXABtAHkAZABlAHMAdABzAG8AdQByAGMAZQA7AEkAbgB0AGUAZwByAGEAdABlAGQAIABTAGUAYwB1AHIAaQB0AHkAPQBmAGEAbABzAGUAOwBVAHMAZQByACAASQBEAD0AcwBhADsAUAB3AGQAPQBzAGEAcABhAHMAcwAhADsARABhAHQAYQBiAGEAcwBlAD0AbQB5AGQAYgA7ACIALABjAG8AbQBwAHUAdABlAHIAbgBhAG0AZQA9ADEAMAAuADEAMAAuADEAMAAuADEAMAAsAHUAcwBlAHIAbgBhAG0AZQA9AGEAZABtAGkAbgBpAHMAdAByAGEAdABvAHIALABwAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAPQBhAGQAbQBpAG4AcABhAHMAcwAiAA==
```

and here is how to replicate at home:

```
$command = 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;" -dest:dbfullsql="Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass"'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$encodedCommand

#  The clip below copies the base64 string to your clipboard for right click and paste.
$encodedCommand | Clip
```

Answer (score 1):

For the executable name, the ***new-alias*** cmdlet can be employed to avoid dealing with spaces or needing to add the executable to the $PATH environment.

```
PS> new-alias msdeploy "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe"
PS> msdeploy ...
```

To list or modify PS aliases also see

```
PS> get-alias
PS> set-alias
```

From [Jeffery Hicks Aarticle](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2014/06/10/exe-alias-in-powershell.aspx)

Other answers address the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run a file in the current directory and don't feel like spelling out the entire path use [Get-Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-7.1):

```
& "$(Get-Location)\example.exe" arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Note the `&` at the start. Spaced arguments are to be placed **after** the quotes.

Comment: For me, this simple answer got me back on track.  The other higher rated answers seem fine for complex coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following code working perfect on my laptop:

```
& $msdeploy `
-source:package="$publishFile" `
-dest:auto,computerName="$server",includeAcls="False",UserName="$username",Password="$password",AuthType="$auth" `
-allowUntrusted  `
-verb:sync  `
-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule `
-disableLink:AppPoolExtension  `
-disableLink:ContentExtension  `
-disableLink:CertificateExtension  `
-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="^(.*Web\.config|.*Environment\.config)$" `
-setParam:name=`"IIS Web Application Name`",value="$appName"
```

Then when I tried to run that directly on one server I started getting those errors `"Unrecognized argument ...etc.... All arguments must begin with "-". "`

After trying all possible workarounds (no success), I found out that Powershell on the server (Windows 2008 R2) was version 3.0, while my laptop has 5.0.  (you can use "$PSVersionTable" to see version).

After [upgrading Powershell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) to latest version it started working again.

Answer (score -1):

So, I ran into a similar problem and chose to solve it this way instead:

1. Escape your quote (") characters with a backtick (`)
2. Surround your new expression with quotes (")
3. Using the call operator (&), issue the command `invoke-expression` on the new string

Example solution:

> & { invoke-expression "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=mysource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`" -dest:dbfullsql=`"Data Source=.\mydestsource;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Pwd=sapass!;Database=mydb;`",computername=10.10.10.10,username=administrator,password=adminpass`"" }

Answer (score -1):

To transfer a batch script using exiftool.exe to a powershell script I had the challange to give '-s, "-s and even ${Filename} to the command and on the other hand fill out variables in these parameters.

For a start: The replacement in using 'echochars' is brilliant. It clearly shows what is grouped as a single parameter and what ends up as the next parameter.

In powershell it is similar to perl (and unix scripting): the used quotes have their meaning.

- strings between "-s. The string will be interpreted (variables filled)
- Strings between '-s. The string will not be interpreted (or verry limited)
- the escape character is ` (the back-quote). The next character looses its special meaning. Comparable with the \ (back stroke) on unix/linux/perl.

Some examples:

```
${ExifArgs} += "-if `"`${FileName} !~ /desktop.ini/i`""
${ExifArgs} += '-dateFormat "%Y\%Y%m\%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"'
${ExifArgs} += ('"' + "-FileName<${NewFotos}\${SourceName}\" + '${DateTimeOriginal}_${ImageWidth}x${ImageHeight}_${Model;s/ //g}_${FileName;s/^.*([0-9]{4})[^0-9].*$/\1/}.%e' + '"')
```

A call to echoargs with the above, produces the next output (numbers are hacked for privacy):

```
Arg 11 is <-if>
Arg 12 is <${FileName} !~ /desktop.ini/i>
Arg 13 is <-dateFormat>
Arg 14 is <%Y\%Y%m\%Y%m%d_%H%M%S>
Arg 15 is <-FileName<D:\Pictures\NewFotos\${DateTimeOriginal}_${ImageWidth}x${ImageHeight}_${Model;s/ //g}_${FileName;s/^.*([0-9]{4})[^0-9].*$/\1/}.%e>
```

See how the first line produces arg 11 and 12: the outher "-s are removed to store the entire line in the array. The inner "-s, quoted by the `-s are there to keep the argument together (while the -if is the previous argument)

The second shows arg 13 and 14: the use of "-s between '-s. No need to escape using `-s.

In the last line (producing arg 15): the single string is constructed by using powershell ()-s and +-s to concatenate a couple of strings to a single string. It uses both " and ' delimited strings to have som ${}-s filled out by powershell and some for exiftool.
And yes, some powershell special characters are transvered into the archuments.