# How to run a SQL Plus script in PowerShell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I am trying to log in to the the Oracle DB using PowerShell and run a script called "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql", When I execute the PS nothing happens.

Here is what I have.

```
$adminLogon = "sys as sysdba/manager@ORCL"
$logon = "sqlplus\sql/manager@ORCL"


$mydata = Invoke-SqlPlus -inputfile       "@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql" $logon
```

I've also tried this.

```
$database = "ORCL";
$user = "sys as sysdba";
$pw = "manager";

sqlplus.exe -d $database -U $user -P $pw -I "@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql"
```

I tried this.

```
& 'C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\sqlplus.exe' 'QE-JDBC-1/manager@ORCL sys as sysdba' '@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql'
```

I get the error, "& : The module 'sqlplus' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module sqlplus'.
At line:5 char:3
+ & $mydata Invoke-SqlPlus -inputfile "@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\Orac ...
+   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlplus\sql/manager@ORCL:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule"

Comment: Have you looked at "How to run exe in powershell with parameters with spaces and quotes", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes. Keith Hill's answer works for me.

Comment: Hey, just in case you still want to run SQL*Plus on PowerShell, take a look at this Module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JS.OracleDatabase

Answer (score 12):

I use the call operator, `&`, as Keith Hill has suggested with the question, [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-exe-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes).

```
& 'path\sqlplus.exe' 'system/password@dbase as sysdba'
```

I placed the username, password in quotes due to the spaces.

To start a script, I add another parameter as follows:

```
 & 'path\sqlplus.exe' 'system/password@dbase as sysdba' '@my_script.sql'
```

If you are receiving the ORA-12154 error, and you know that other users have
established connections (which implies that the database listener is running
properly); I would then examine if SQL*Plus can find my tnsname file.

My first task would be to see if I can tnsping as follows in Windows cmd.exe:

```
tnsping orcl
```

It will confirm that a connection can (or can not be established).

If it cannot, I would check to see if the environment variable, ORACLE_HOME,
is set.  SQL*Plus uses this to find tnsname.ora file.

If it is not set, I would execute this statement in PowerShell (to establish
this environment variable):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME", "C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1" , "User")
```

Next, I would retry to tnsping (identified above).

Once successful, I would re-try to execute the script running command above.

Comment: I get this error, "ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified", when I use, "& 'C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\sqlplus.exe' 'system/manager@ORCL as sysdba' '@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql'".

Comment: Have you set your ORACLE_HOME environment variable? Can you connect in Windows cmd.exe mode (e.g. can you tnsping orcl)?

Comment: Do I leave the "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME", "oracle_home_path" , "User")" as is or do I need to change it? If I do change it what should each one be changed to?

Comment: I ran the environment change and rebooted and tried again, I still get the same results. Should I of left the "User" unchanged or changed it something else? I left it as just "User".

Comment: In windows cmd.exe mode, can you tnsping orcl?  If you cannot, it means that SQL*Plus is having issues with your configuration. Do you have an entry in the tnsname.ora file for orcl?

Comment: The tnsping cannot ping the DB, but I know that I have made and can still make a connection with JDBC to this database using the same information.

Comment: <alias>= [ (DESCRIPTION_LIST =  
   (DESCRIPTION=
     [ (SDU=2048) ] 
     [ (ADDRESS_LIST=    
     
       (ADDRESS=
  [ (COMMUNITY=<community_name>) ] 
  (PROTOCOL=tcp)
  (HOST=<hostname>)
  (PORT=<portnumber (1521 is a standard port used)>)
       )
       [ (ADDRESS=
    (PROTOCOL=ipc)
    (KEY=<ipckey (PNPKEY is a standard key used)>) 
  )
       ]
       [ (ADDRESS=
    [ (COMMUNITY=<community_name>) ]
    (PROTOCOL=decnet)
    (NODE=<nodename>)
    (OBJECT=<objectname>)
  )
       ]
     [ ) ] 
     [ (CONNECT_DATA=
  (SID=<oracle_sid>)
  [ (GLOBAL_NAME=<global_database_name>) ]

Comment: With most configurations, SQL*Plus relies on the tnsnames.ora file to establish a connection with your database. If you cannot tnsping, you will not be able to establish a connection (cmd.exe nor PowerShell). Compare your jdbc connection with the jdbc parameters. By the way, 'User" is acceptable.

Comment: )    ]
    [ (SOURCE_ROUTE=yes) ]  
   )
  (DESCRIPTION=     
    [ (SDU=2048) ] 
     [ (ADDRESS_LIST= ]    
       (ADDRESS
  [ (COMMUNITY=<community_name>) ]
  (PROTOCOL=tcp)
  (HOST=<hostname>)
  (PORT=<portnumber (1521 is a standard port used)>) )
       [ (ADDRESS=
(PROTOCOL=ipc)
 (KEY=<ipckey (PNPKEY is a standard key used)>)
       )
       ]
     [ ) ]   
 [ (CONNECT_DATA=
  (SID=<oracle_sid>)
  [ (GLOBAL_NAME=<global_database_name>) ]
       )
     ]
     [ (SOURCE_ROUTE=yes) ]
   )
   [ (CONNECT_DATA=
       (SID=<oracle_sid>)
       [ (GLOBAL_NAME=<global_database_name>) ] 
 [ ) ]

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
$cmd = "cmd.exe"
$args = ("/c sqlplus {0}/{1}@{2}:{3}/{4} @{5} {6}" -f $userName, $password, $tnsAlias, $port, $dbInstance, $sqlScript, $outputFileName)
&$cmd $args
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Windows PowerShell command prompt the code does not require variable setting or anything fancy. Just do this:

`sqlplus ElBankoUser\SupaSecretyPass "@C:\Users\ElBankoUser\Documents\MaFancySckrp.sql"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.NET Oracle library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) DLL, just make sure you have the required DLL file under the `lib` folder

```
Add-Type -Path "lib\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

$query = "select  1 as Col1, 2 as Col2, 3 as Col3 from dual
          union
          select  4 as Col1, 5 as Col2, 6 as Col3 from dual
          union
          select  7 as Col1, 8 as Col2, 9 as Col3 from dual"

$cn   = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection -ArgumentList "TNS-ConnectionString-Here"
$cmd  = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand    -ArgumentList $query

$cmd.Connection = $cn

try {
    $cn.Open()

    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    while ($reader.Read()) {
        $col1 = $reader["Col1"]
        $col2 = $reader["Col2"]
        $col3 = $reader["Col3"]

        Write-Host $col1, $col2, $col3
    }

} catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
} finally {
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $cn.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this?

sqlplus -s $adminLogin "@C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oracle\OracleCleanTest.sql"

-s just suppresses the sqlplus banner.