# Start the logon script first before app in startup start

Tags: windows, powershell

I assigned in the gpo a powershell script as logon script.
[image]

All my clients are Windows 7 based machine. Every clients have an application in the startup folder, that will start, when the machine is getting started.

[image]

The application that is getting started, depends on that powershell script. Because the powershell script will copy all settings from network share location, that the application needs to start.
My problem is now, that the application starts faster than even the powershell script starts to copy the file from networkshare. So the application can never use the settings.
My question is, how can avoid the application starts before the powershell script is finish with the copy without any extension app.

Comment: Can't you run the program at the end of the logon script?

Comment: There's a group policy setting to make logon scripts run synchronously, i.e., the logon doesn't continue until the logon script exits.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: How can I do logon scripts synchronously?

Comment: He already said group policy.... Google "logon script synchronously" and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I tried one hour ago and it works as expected. Thanks so much guys for helping me. My boss will be happy about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure, I recommend that the best practice in this case would be to simply remove programs, which are dependent on script, from Startup folder. Then launch them from PowerShell at the end of your logon script.

To execute a program from PowerShell use the Call operator. You can refer [here on other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes).