# msdeploy error:Unrecognized argument "IIS Web Application Name"

Tags: batch-file, iis, msdeploy

I am using a bat file which is inside a folder with my zip file

my bat file contains

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" - source:package="Release_2060.zip" -setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='MyappsName' -dest:auto -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="Config/*"
```

I am executing the file as a administrator and i keep getting this error

Unrecognized argument 'IIS Web Application Name'

Any ideas?Thanks

Comment: Upgrading to latest Powershell version might help. See my sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195230/3606250)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue and for me escaping the quotes did the trick. Also you can try using "value" instead like this:

```
 -setParam:name=`"IIS Web Application Name`",value=MyappsName
```

In my case I'm using Powershell, so to escape the quotes I used ` but for a batch file I believe is \ so this might work for you:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" -source:package="Release_2060.zip" -setParam:\"IIS Web Application Name\",value="MyappsName" -dest:auto -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="Config/*"
```

Hope this helps and is not too late.