# How do I run a *.exe file from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a folder at C:\Folder that has files input.xml, output.xml and licensegenerator.exe.  Licensegenerator.exe takes variables that we put into input.xml and creates a temporary license for one of our programs using the output.xml file.  We typically do this via command line by navigating to the C:\Folder directory, then running the command:

```
LicenseGenerator.exe "C:\Folder\input.xml" "C:\Folder\output.xml"
```

I'm attempting to write a script to do the exact same thing in PowerShell, but I'm struggling...  Here's what I have:

```
$inputtest = "C:\Folder\Input.xml"
$outputtest = "C:\Folder\Output.xml"
$licensegen = "C:\Folder\LicenseGenerator.exe"

Invoke-Command $licensegen "$inputtest" "$outputtest"
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'C:\Folder\Output.xml'.
At line:5 char:1
+ Invoke-Command $licengegen "$inputtest" "$outputtest"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I have also tried running with `Invoke-Expression` but get the exact same error (except it says "Invoke-Expression" at the beginning).  Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: & $licensegen "$inputtest" "$outputtest" did the trick.  Thank you all!

Comment: This question has already been discussed in detail here, and has some exceptionally good and unusual answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [call operator (`&`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```
& $licensegen "$inputtest" "$outputtest"
```

[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2) is essentially for running scriptblocks on other hosts and/or in other user contexts.

Answer (score 4):

[Start-Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)
is great because you can runas, redirect output, hide the child processes window and much more.

`Start-Process -FilePath $licensegen -Argumentlist $inputtest,$outputtest`

Answer (score 2):

& "[path] command" [arguments]

Just replace Invoke-Command with &