# Powershell escaping a blank space in a variable

Tags: powershell, escaping, invoke

The following example script terminates at folder due to the space between name and number. How do I run the full string?

```
$path = "C:\folder1\folder 2"

Invoke-Expression "$path\DB_Migration\Migrate.exe --timeout=300 -a $path\Server\Application.Core.dll -db SqlServer -conn $connectionstring"
```

`$path` is actually `$PSScriptRoot` on a server where I cannot simply rename the folder.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes e.g. `Invoke-Expression "'$path\DB_Migration\Migrate.exe' --timeout=300..."`

Comment: Wouldn't the single quote prevent the variable substitution?

Comment: @Jinx - If you have double-quotes on the 'outside' and single-quotes on the 'inside', substitution still works.  Give it a try: `$world = 'world'; "'Hello $world'"`

Comment: Tested and you are correct that the single quotes do allow the variable to be parsed (which is good to know - thanks) however they then prevent the parameters being accepted

Comment: why not just use `start-process` instead of  `invoke-expression`? then you wouldnt have to cramp everything into a single string

Answer (score 0):

First, using `Invoke-Expression` should be avoid

[Avoid using Invoke-Expression (Microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2)

Suggestion: Use & operator.

Read: [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes)