# Using Stack from Powershell, how do I pass test arguments that include a space?

Tags: powershell, haskell, command-line-arguments, haskell-stack

I need to pass the string "fail log" as a tasty pattern argument when running tasty tests out of stack.

This is quite straight forward in bash:

`PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p \"fail log\""`

But trying to achieve the same using Powershell is driving me nuts:

---

`PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p ""fail"" "`

works (runs tests) when there is no space

---

`PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p ""fail log"" "`

Error parsing targets: Directory not found: log

---

`` PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p `"fail log`"" ``

tries install a package called log

---

`PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p \"fail log\""`

option --ta: unterminated string: endOfInput

---

`PS C:\Pyrethrum> stack test --fast --ta "-p /fail log/ "`

... builds but pattern needs quotes

pyrethrum-0.1.0.0: test (suite: pyrethrum-test, args: -p /fail log/)

option -p: Could not parse pattern

---

What is the correct command line to get this to run in Powershell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes)

Comment: pass params in an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, **the way PowerShell passes arguments to external programs is broken up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x**,  and requires you to not just satisfy PowerShell's *own* syntax requirements with respect to embedded `"`, but to *additionally* escape them for the target executable, typically with `\`:

```
 # `" is needed for PowerShell, \ is needed for stack
 stack test --fast --ta "-p \`"fail log\`""
```

Since your outer `"..."` string references no PowerShell variables and contains no subexpressions, i.e., since no string interpolation is required, you can use a `'...'`, a literal PowerShell string instead, which simplifies matters a bit:

```
 stack test --fast --ta '-p \"fail log\"'
```

In short: To **pass `"` characters *embedded in an argument* to an *external program*** from PowerShell:

- use `` \`" `` inside `"..."`
- use `\"` inside `'...'`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details, also with respect to a *potential future fix* and a helper function that hides the bug.