# Call system capability from self hosted agent on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

**Problem:**

Inside my release pipeline, I want to use the `sqlpackage.exe`, which is installed on my self hosted agent.

---

**Investigations:**

- On the self hosted agent, SqlPackage.exe was automatically detected
  as *System Capability*: [DevOps > SystemCapability >
  SQLPackage.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Or1v.png)
- It seems, that the SystemCapability has also been found from the Agent job, since `sqlpackage == exists` is defined as a demand here: [Agent Job > Demand > sqlpackage == exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr0Nv.png)
- This way of calling the system capability "sqlpackage" didn't work: [Failed function call in Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4bXZ.png)

---

Any ideas how to call the SqlPackage from my hosted agent?

Comment: What errors were you getting when you called it from PowerShell?  Maybe take a glance at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674950/10761889), since I would bet it might be because you aren't using the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have few options:

- call full path `C:\......\sqlpackage.exe` (the simplest way)
- use [Get-SqlPackagePath](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PublishDacPac/1.0.2.3224/Content/public%5CGet-SqlPackagePath.ps1) function to get path to SQL Package and then use this full path

```
function Get-SqlPackagePath {
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Find path to specific version of SqlPackage.exe
 
    .DESCRIPTION
    Finds the path to specific version of SqlPackage.exe
 
    Written by (c) Dr. John Tunnicliffe, 2019 https://github.com/DrJohnT/PublishDacPac
    This PowerShell script is released under the MIT license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 
    .PARAMETER Version
    Defines the specific version of SqlPackage.exe to which you wish to obtain the path
        latest = use the latest version of SqlPackage.exe
        150 = SQL Server 2019
        140 = SQL Server 2017
        130 = SQL Server 2016
        120 = SQL Server 2014
        110 = SQL Server 2012
 
    .OUTPUTS
    The full path to the specific version of SqlPackage.exe you requested
 
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-SqlPackagePath -Version 130
 
    Return the full path to a specific version of SqlPackage.exe
 
    .EXAMPLE
    Get-SqlPackagePath -Version latest
 
    Return the full path to a latest version of SqlPackage.exe
 
    .NOTES
    This module requires SqlPackage.exe to be installed on the host machine.
    This can be done by installing Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017
 
#>
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateSet('150', '140', '130', '120', '110', 'latest')]
        [string]$Version
    )

    $ExeName = "SqlPackage.exe";
    try {
        # always return x64 version if present
        $SqlPackageExes = Get-Childitem -Path "${env:ProgramFiles}\Microsoft SQL Server\$Version" -Recurse -Include $ExeName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
        foreach ($SqlPackageExe in $SqlPackageExes) {
            $SqlPackageExePath = $SqlPackageExe.FullName;
            $ProductVersion = $SqlPackageExe.VersionInfo | Select-Object ProductVersion;
            break;
        }

        if (!($SqlPackageExePath)) {
            # try to find x86 version
            $SqlPackageExes = Get-Childitem -Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SQL Server\$Version" -Recurse -Include $ExeName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;

            foreach ($SqlPackageExe in $SqlPackageExes) {
                $SqlPackageExePath = $SqlPackageExe.FullName;
                $ProductVersion = $SqlPackageExe.VersionInfo | Select-Object ProductVersion;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!($SqlPackageExePath)) {
            $VsPaths = Resolve-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\*\*\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\$Version";
            foreach ($VsPath in $VsPaths) {
                $SqlPackageExes = Get-Childitem -Path $VsPath -Recurse -Include $ExeName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                foreach ($SqlPackageExe in $SqlPackageExes) {
                    $SqlPackageExePath = $SqlPackageExe.FullName;
                    $ProductVersion = $SqlPackageExe.VersionInfo | Select-Object ProductVersion;

                    break;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!($SqlPackageExePath)) {
            $VsPaths = Resolve-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio*\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\$Version";

            foreach ($VsPath in $VsPaths) {
                $SqlPackageExes = Get-Childitem -Path $VsPath -Recurse -Include $ExeName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                foreach ($SqlPackageExe in $SqlPackageExes) {
                    $SqlPackageExePath = $SqlPackageExe.FullName;
                    $ProductVersion = $SqlPackageExe.VersionInfo | Select-Object ProductVersion;
                    break;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Write-Verbose "SqlPackage $ProductVersion found here $SqlPackageExePath";
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Get-SqlPackagePath failed with error $Error";
    }
    return $SqlPackageExePath;
}
```

- call [Agent REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) endpoint with enabled `includeCapabilities` and then parse response to get sqlpackage ful path and use full path

Comment: Thanks, calling with the absolute path works for me. 
Is ist also possible to call without the absolute path, since it's already a "environment variable" and defined under system capabilities?

I'd like to call it in powershell like `& SqlPackage`.

Comment: You need to add it to PATH env variable to do that in context of user which runs service for the agent. Having this as capability is not enough.

Comment: @user16231674 can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?