# GCC arm compiler command produces errors on PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gcc, arm

The command below produces an error in powershell.exe:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc   -mthumb    -mcpu=cortex-m4     -march=armv7e-m    -save-temps  -nostdlib 
  -O0   -Wl,-Map,"app.map"   -Wl,-T"tm4c123gh6pm.lds"    app_main.c  app_2.c -o  app_output.elf
```

[image: 1]

It does however work without error in cmd.

Comment: Perhaps try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22247408/4190564), or maybe this [--%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13770568/4190564)

Comment: Please remove the image of the error which is an essential part of your question, and paste the actual error content from PowerShell, formatted as code, instead. There is an [edit] button available for such purposes.

Comment: `,` is a special character in powershell but just a normal one in cmd. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)